# Strategy to make UIKit shorter in Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am sick with iOS development long names in UIKit.
Previously, In Objective-C I created a macro file and Objective C++ for myself which shorten all long names in Objective-C, for example

```
Cell = UITableViewCell
Table = UITableView
Row = NSIndexPath

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

become

```
Cell* cellAtRow(Table* table, Row* row){
//shorten Objective-C++ code
}
```

And I find this strategy is extremely effective, reduce 1/4 development times. The code is still easy to read, develop and test. Only one drawback is the project can be used by myself only.

But in Swift, there is no macro as well as a C++ bridge like Objective-C++

Now I am sick with long names in Swift UIKit and want to make it shorter again.

Anyone has similar ideas ? Anyone has effective strategy to get the same result ?

Using something like objc_msgSend and sel_registerName is not a good option, I have tried but it does not work well.

Comment: Type Alias Declaration https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID361

Comment: Try out SwiftUI, I guess?

Comment: If changing this reduces your development time by 1/4; Teach me how you develop.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`typealias`**

```
typealias Cell = UITableViewCell
typealias Table = UITableView
typealias Row = IndexPath
```

In Swift, use `IndexPath` instead of `NSIndexPath`